# Python re.sub to change only the word 'a' as opposed to every instance of 'a' as a letter

Tags: python, regex, string

For example, let's say I want to change every word 'a' into 'an' in the following text:

```
"a apple is a| awesome fruit."
```

Assume that the "|" character is there as a garbage character that needs to be worked around.
I want the end product to be as follows:

```
"an apple is an| awesome fruit."
```

So far, the closest I've gotten is with the following code:

```
>>> s = 'a apple is a| awesome fruit.'
>>> regex = '[^A-Za-z0-9](a)[^A-Za-z0-9]'
>>> s = re.sub(regex, 'an', s)
>>> s
'a apple isan awesome fruit.'
```

'a' showing up at the beginning of the string isn't being affected at all, while the 'a' followed up by garbage mutilates the string in that area. I understand why it's happening this way, I just don't know how I should make the regex pattern to fit this situation. My plan is to only change the substring group (a), but I don't know how to work with that in re.sub. How can I only substitute the substring group? Are there any better ways to use a regex pattern for this situation?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of word boundaries (`\b` it matches between a `\w` class and a `\W` class (or `\w` and `^` or `\w` and `$`):

```
>>> s = 'a apple is a| awesome fruit.'
>>> regex = r'\ba\b'
>>> s = re.sub(regex, 'an', s)
>>> s
'an apple is an| awesome fruit.'
```

Answer (score 1):

`\b` for word boundaries is a good answer here, the more general construct is called "lookahead" and "lookbehind". Here it would look like:

```
re.sub(r'\ba\b', 'an', s)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'((?<=\W)|^)a((?=\W)|$)', 'an', s)
```

Comment: Indeed! I just try to avoid lookarounds as much as possible for performance reasons :)

Comment: @jerry It's not any differently performant than a regex matching `(\W|^)a(\W|$)`. Are you sure you're not thinking of backreferences?

Comment: Lookarounds and captures take a little more processing, because the regex has to get anchored first, then match whatever's inside the lookaround then come back later to match whatever's been matched. It's a little easier to understand with [this](http://regex101.com/r/wR2yT7/#debugger) compared to [this](http://regex101.com/r/hI1tW0). I also mentioned captures because captures mean that the script will have to allocate some more memory to store the capture. And your regex could be improved a little with: `(?<=\W|^)a(?=\W|$)`

Comment: @jerry Oddly enough I tried `(?<=\W|^)a(?=\W|$)` and it complained about variable length lookarounds. I'm not arguing that `\b` isn't faster here.

Comment: Oh, right, oops sorry! Yea, python doesn't support variable width lookbehinds. I think I see where the misunderstanding comes then: in my original point, I meant performance in terms of processing time/requirements and not as end result.